# Compose Desktop draw Text out of screen using Canvas

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I want to draw a text using `Canvas`.
here is my code:

```
val firstOffset = Offset(x = 0F, y = 0F)
val secondOffset = Offset(x = 0F, y = 1000F)
val thirdOffset = Offset(x = 0F, y = 1080F)
Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.width(priceBarItemWidth)
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .pointerHoverIcon(
                PointerIcon(Cursor(N_RESIZE_CURSOR))
            )
    ) {
        drawText(
            textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
            text = "qwerty",
            topLeft = firstOffset,
            style = style
        )
    }
```

when I use `firstOffset` text goes to top left of screen
when I use `secondOffset` text goes to bottom left of screen
and when I use `thirdOffset` i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
maxHeight(-30) must be >= than minHeight(0)
```

I want to draw this text out of screen (I want to develop a scrollable list using Canvas and I know there is better ways to do this)
so the question is how can I draw texts out of screen to bring scroll function to my custom list!

and the original code is below:

```
val containerSize by service.containerSize.collectAsState()
Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.width(priceBarItemWidth)
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .pointerHoverIcon(
                PointerIcon(Cursor(N_RESIZE_CURSOR))
            )
    ) {
        if (containerSize.height == 0) return@Canvas
        var currentHeight = 25 * (priceBarItemHeightInPx + 
            priceBarSpaceBetweenItemInPx)
        prices.forEachIndexed { index, fl ->
            drawText(
                textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
                text = fl.toString(),
                topLeft = Offset(x = 0F, y = 0F),
                style = style
            )
            currentHeight -= (priceBarItemHeightInPx + priceBarSpaceBetweenItemInPx)
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Jorn you can. Using any draw Modifier, including Canvas(Spacer with Modifier.drawBehind) and even if Canvas has Modifier.size(0.dp) you can draw anywhere or out of screen let alone Canvas or Composable itself as long as you don't clip it. Not available in OPs code but there is something wrong with the calculation that returning negative value he sets as height modifier

Comment: And this `if (containerSize.height == 0) return@Canvas` is a bad thing to do which causes exceptions in many situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to drawText function passing Constraints with negative height in calculation here.

https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/ui/ui-text/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextPainter.kt;drc=4d53400eca9f3ac90c3a3f6cffcbc5bf492ec536;l=390

Passing topLeft with bigger than text height, when you don't set `size` param of `drawText`, returns negative maxHeight which is not allowed. Passing smaller maxHeight than minHeight also not allowed for Constraints as well.

You can set `size` param of `drawText` function or you can use `translate` function of DrawScope as

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun CanvasTextSample() {

    val list = remember {
        listOf(
            "Hello",
            "World",
            "Text1",
            "Text2",
            "Text3",
            "Text4",
        )
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp).fillMaxSize().padding(top = 60.dp)
    ) {

        val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()

        var offset by remember {
            mutableStateOf(0f)
        }

        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                        offset += dragAmount.y
                    }
                }
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .border(1.dp, Color.Red)
        ) {

            list.fastForEachIndexed { index, text ->
                translate(
                    left = 100f,
                    top = offset + index * 20.dp.toPx()
                ) {
                    drawText(
                        textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
                        text = text,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wish to center Text horizontally inside Canvas use textMeasurer.measure() to get TextLayoutResult and center Text using size returned from it and Canvas size.